# ZeroDivisionError: float division error while calculating percentile rank in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentile

I am trying to calculate numerical data ranks between the subgroups grouped by "Variable".

But some variable has only NaN values in value1. So i am getting **ZeroDivisionError: float division error** . How to solve this issue

```
   df1.assign(percentile=df1.groupby("variable")['value1'].rank(pct=True)
```

Data in dataframe `df1` :

```
         Date        variable         value1
0     2013-09-30   VTL US Equity     3.56
1     2008-02-29   GTXI US Equity      NaN
2     2007-07-31   OVID US Equity      NaN
3     2001-10-31   HOV US Equity     4.8548
4     2014-12-31   HOV US Equity     2.2006
5     2015-01-31   HOV US Equity     1.7636
6     2015-02-28   HOV US Equity     1.9174
```

Error: 
  *File "pandas_libs\groupby_helper.pxi", in pandas._libs.groupby.group_rank_float64
ZeroDivisionError: float division*

Comment: working fine on my side

Comment: Let me check once again. The dataframe has 30000 rows. I copied only few rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to simply replace `NaN` values in that column with extremely small values before running the operation using [`Dataframe.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

```
from sys.float_info import epsilon

df1.assign(
    percentile = df1.fillna(value={'value1': epsilon}).groupby("variable")['value1'].rank(pct=True)
)
```